# Antlr4 float parse

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

I have following antlr4 code:

```
decnum returns [double value] :
    NUMBER {$value = Double.parseDouble($NUMBER.text);}
    ;

POINT : '.';
INTNUMBER : ('0'..'9')+ ;
NUMBER : INTNUMBER (POINT INTNUMBER)?;
```

When I do `System.out.println(parser.decnum().value);` on `String s = 1.2`, it works correctly. But also it works on these strings:

```
"0001.2000."
"0001.2000.asfgheg"
".0001.2000.37"
"5.61345345ggdfhfjg"
```

and doesn't work on `"5"`

What am I doing wrong?

Also, why antlr4 tries to evaluate expressions even if parse fails? I'm getting `token recognition error` but the result of evaluation is printed anyway. How to disable it?

Answer (score 4):

Starting with the last item: the expressions are getting evaluated whether or not the parse is successful because you included the evaluation as part of the rules. The recommended way to use ANTLR 4 is allowing it to simply build a parse tree, and then using listeners and/or visitors after the parse is complete to perform the desired evaluation. For example, your `decnum` rule should look like this:

```
decnum
  : NUMBER
  ;
```

Going on to the input `"5"`. This input does not match any rule you listed above, because no rule in your grammar includes the input character `"`. When ANTLR 4 reaches this character and no rule matches, it recovers by skipping the character and continuing with the next one. The first time this happens, ANTLR 4 will essentially be looking at this to find the next token: `5"`.

When ANTLR 4 starts matching `5"`, it determines that both the `INTNUMBER` and `NUMBER` rules match the input `5`, and this is the longest match because no rule matches the longer sequence `5"`. ANTLR 4 can only assign one token type to each token, and this is performed before any parse rule sees the token. Rather than assign both values `INTNUMBER` and `NUMBER` to `5`, it determines the token type for this case according to the order in which the rules appear in the grammar; i.e. ANTLR 4 matches `5` as an `INTNUMBER` token that is *not* also a `NUMBER` token. Finally, ANTLR 4 skips the last `"` character for the same reason it skipped the first.

A similar evaluation sequence is used for the other strings you gave. For example, `"0001.2000.asfgheg"` is matched as:

- `"`: ignored error (no match)
- `.`: `POINT`
- `0001.2000`: `NUMBER`
- `.`: `POINT`
- `a`: ignored error (no match)
- `s`: ignored error (no match)
- `f`: ignored error (no match)
- `g`: ignored error (no match)
- `h`: ignored error (no match)
- `e`: ignored error (no match)
- `g`: ignored error (no match)
- `"`: ignored error (no match)

To the parser, the above appears as just `POINT`, `NUMBER`, `POINT`.

If you want to include the skipped characters I mentioned above as syntax errors in the parse tree, you can do so by adding the following as the last rule in your lexer. This rule matches any single character, but only if no other rule matches, which is exactly what the error recovery mechanism is matching when you don't include the rule. This rule will pass the error characters to the parser as a single `ErrorCharacter` token.

```
ErrorCharacter
  : .
  ;
```

Comment: Thanks for great explanation! However, I didn't understand how to make antlr fail-fast? Really, I need an exception if input is mismatched, only exception without trying to ignore errors. How could I implement this?